# Laravel routes defined but shows empty page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-route

In web.php routes file, I have defined all the routes in route group, but some of them do not work and display a blank page but shows the page when defined outside of route group without prefix.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController')->except(['destroy']);
    Route::get('/category/delete/{category}', 'CategoryController@destroy')->name('category.delete');

    Route::resource('/post', 'PostController')->except(['destroy']);
    Route::get('/post/delete/{post}', 'PostController@destroy')->name('post.delete');

    Route::get('/post/{post}/restore', 'PostController@restore')->name('post.restore');
    Route::get('/post/{post}/forceDelete', 'PostController@forceDelete')->name('post.forceDelete');
    Route::resource('/tag', 'TagController')->except(['destroy']);
    Route::get('/tag/{tag}/delete', 'TagController@destroy')->name('tag.destroy');

    Route::resource('user', 'UserController')->except(['destroy']);
    Route::get('/user/{user}/delete', 'UserController@destroy')->name('user.delete');
    Route::get('user/{user}/admin', 'UserController@makeAdmin')->name('user.admin')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/user/{user}/makeUser', 'UserController@makeUser')->name('user.user');
    Route::get('user/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->name('user.profile');
    Route::post('user/profile/update', 'ProfileController@update')->name('user.profile.update');
});
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `php artisan route:list` command?

Comment: use the artisan command above and review those routes that aren't listed if any

Comment: already tried that(show that routes are defined) and also used route:clear

Comment: You should also make sure that you are authenticated because of `auth` middleware, check and see if this route works: `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('home');`
if you need Laravel scaffold authentication you need to run `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Route list show there is Auth middleware

Comment: Can you make sure that you are authenticated and login/register routes/views exist?

Comment: Can you clarify, which route are you trying to access and what are you writing in browser? Your question just showing the list of route but it's not showing how you are trying to access. As a result we have no clue why you are facing this problem.

Comment: An idea; when VueJS fails to render, sometime the whole `body` html tag gets empty and you see a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You're routes are getting conflicted with each other, the routes generated with `Route::resource` are causing conflict with the routes that you have defined by yourself`enter code here`.

There could be an issue here

```
Route::get('/user/{user}/delete', 'UserController@destroy')->name('user.delete');
Route::get('user/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->name('user.profile');
```

`'profile'` might be getting passed as a parameter user, throwing a blank page.

Comment: `When the route name conflict happens, laravel throws a blank page` I cannot reproduce this. Are you certain about that?

Comment: Plus, I don't see any route name conflict

Comment: If you can share which routes are not working, then i might get more understanding of the issue, i have had such issue, that was my problem, i updated the answer with the details.